# my question is about render and texture

Tags: rendering, texturing, lighting

I'm using blender 2.79 and my final render comes out as pixels and texture is not very sharp at all. Render Preset settings are as required, motion blur, node editor, color balance is not very bright either. Is there anything I'm missing . [image]

Comment: Please use your operating system's or blender's screenshot functionality rather than taking a photo of your screen.

Answer (score 0):

You are currently viewing the scene in the rendered preview in the 3D view. In order to actually render the scene you need to press <kbd>F12</kbd> or select *Render > Render Image* in the top toolbar.

The preview uses very few samples which results in the noisy look.

Comment: thanks a lot,  I thought about doing it. Is there another way to check final quality of the texture in 3D preview. I have more stuff to add in the scene.

Comment: @sjblend depends on what you mean by "quality of the texture". You can select *Texture* or *Material* for shading the the 3D view. This however won't accurately shade/light it, but allows to see the texture applied. For a higher quality preview (which will still not be on par with the final render) you can increase the render samples for the preview in the render tab listed in the *Sampling* panel.

Comment: Now, in blender 2.80, there is a better render preview, that doesn't have the "pixels".

Comment: To reduce the proper render times, you can add the "Denoiser" node in the compositing tab. Just check "Use Nodes" at the top and stick it in between the Render Layer and Composite nodes. That way you won't need so many samples.